# Laptop extremely slow after battery drained below 10%

Tags: power-management, laptop, asus, battery

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with a Asus Zenbook (UX303UA). If I'm running the computer with battery, the perfomance drops dramatically as soon as the battery indicator reports that only 10% capacity is left. After that, the computer is almost unusable.

Is there a way to configure this? Apparently the system is going into an extreme-power-saving mode.. but I'd rather have 10 minutes with normal performance than 20 minutes which are unusable....

Comment: When the computer slows down when the battery is almost empty, it's a warning to either 1) plug in the AC adapter, or 2) perform a clean shutdown ASAP, or 3) change the battery with a spare. Don't try and do what you're asking.

Comment: You really shouldn't even drain your laptop's battery to 10%.